# Consulta baseada em parâmetro no SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, parâmetros, stored-procedures

Tenho uma situação em que preciso trazer resultados dependendo do parâmetro informado. Se eu informar algum número, que seria o código, ele traria apenas o resultado que tenha o código. Se eu não informar nada, ele traria todos os resultados da tabela. Em outras palavras, preciso deixar o parâmetro como opcional. Segue o código:

```
create procedure procedure_pedido
    @COD_PEDIDO int = null
as
    begin
        select 
        cod_pedido as PEDIDO, 
        descricao as DESCRICAO      
        from pedido         
        where cod_pedido = @COD_PEDIDO
    end
```

Eu queria usar essa condição do parâmetro se possível sem `if`. Mas não sei como faria isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer do seguinte modo:

```
Select 
  cod_pedido as PEDIDO, 
  descricao as DESCRICAO      
From pedido         
Where @COD_PEDIDO is Null OR cod_pedido = @COD_PEDIDO
```

Se o parâmetro for nulo a condição vai ser verdadeira para todas as linhas da tabela.

Comment: Certinho! Funcionou perfeitamente!